# Spinner populated with multiple documents from Firestore how to delete selected item?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, spinner

As you can see from my title I have a spinner populated with data retrieved from Firestore, now I just can't figure out how to delete the selected item from the Firestore, to be specific how can I get the document ID of a select item so I can delete it, Here's the solution for anyone interested:

```
private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_booking_dates);

    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

    final Button save = findViewById(R.id.saveDate);

    final List<String> idlist = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    //list.add("Choose a Date");

    db.collection("BookingDates").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                    list.add(document.get("Date").toString());
                    idlist.add(document.getId());


                }


                final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(BookingDates.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
                        ,list);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,final int i, long l) {
                        String id = idlist.get(i);
                        Toast.makeText(BookingDates.this, "ID: " + id , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                String id = idlist.get(i);
                                db.collection("BookingDates").document(id).delete();
                                Toast.makeText(BookingDates.this, "ID: " + id + " /DELETED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                    }
                });

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(BookingDates.this, task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To delete a document you will need to knows its ID. So when you add the date to the spinner, you will also need to keep the document ID somewhere to be able to look it up when the user clicks the <kbd>Done</kbd> button.

A overly simple example:

```
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
    list.add(document.get("Date").toString());
    idlist.add(document.getId();
}
```

Where `idlist` is just a list of IDs, similar to `list` being a list of dates.

```
final List<String> idlist = new ArrayList<>();
```

And then when the user selects an item in the spinner:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
  String id = idlist.get(position);
  db.collection("BookingDates").doc(id).delete();
}
```